# How to move/transition HTML youtube video to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

I currently have the following YouTube Video in my site:

```
<object  id="vid" style="width:34%;height:32%;top:44.6%;position:fixed;left:33%;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/sGVfhMMZEPA" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/sGVfhMMZEPA" /></object>
```

When a user click on the button I want all the elements to move to the right. Here is the js code:

```
 $("#AboutUs").click(function(){
                $('#vid').animate({left: '55%'},500);});
```

Now everything else in the page moves accept for the YouTUbe Video. Any ideas why? Here is a fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P2jN8/)

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: I've just posted a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the object with a div, and move the contents of the the id and styling into that div:

```
<div id="vid" style="width:34%;height:32%;top:44.6%;position:fixed;left:33%;">
    <object data="http://www.youtube.com/v/sGVfhMMZEPA" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/sGVfhMMZEPA" /></object>
</div>
```

Here is an updated working fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P2jN8/1/)